# Understanding Ubuntu LTS Relationship with Debian Testing and Update Process

Tags: updates, lts, debian

I'm looking to understand the relationship between Ubuntu LTS and Debian's testing branch. I've heard that Ubuntu LTS is based on Debian Testing, but I'm unsure about the update process. Does Ubuntu LTS receive updates continuously as Debian Testing evolves, or is it more like a snapshot of a specific point in time? I'm considering whether Debian Stable could be an alternative for me if Ubuntu LTS and Debian Stable receive updates in a similar manner. Could someone please clarify how the update process works for Ubuntu LTS and how it compares to Debian Stable?

Comment: Ubuntu *development* feeds from Debian *sid/testing*, ie. what is currently *mantic* (where it not past *feature freeze* and thus *taps* from Debian are now closed)... Updated packages are security fixes from later release/versions backported to the existing version, as befits the *stable* release model of both Debian & Ubuntu.

Comment: The Ubuntu *development* release cycle runs for two years, the current cycle started the week after release of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. During that full two year cycle; 3 *snapshots* of progress are released; those being 22.10, 23.04 and the final will be 23.10 - each a mini six-month cycle within the full two year LTS cycle; with the last six months mostly *polishing* & some newer LTS software stacks being included (eg. GNOME, Linux kernel etc). As the *cups* change didn't make it into 23.10; it's been delayed until 24.10, ie. the next LTS cycle. Debian is **only one** upstream source

Comment: FYI:  In the manner in which you are asking, I don't see any differences  (and I'm using my Debian *trixie* system now, but have used my Ubuntu *mantic* system most of today). Differences exist but on a more subtle level given they both use the same packaging & *stable* release model... ie. Debian has a person in charge of a package, Ubuntu makes a team (*many people*) the owners etc or differences that won't really impact the end-users or "update process" your question relates to.

Comment: Does Debian stable do the package freezing as Ubuntu LTS? If so, is the Debian stable's update process same as Ubuntu LTS?

Comment: Thanks it helps @guiverc

Comment: A difference between "*Ubuntu LTS and how it compares to Debian Stable*" is when they release. Ubuntu LTS releases are on ***even*** years in April (one exception being Ubuntu 6.06 LTS which was late; released in June 2006 thus 6.06), where as Debian releases are on ***odd*** years "when they are "~ready" (ie. date decided in the weeks beforehand; 12 or *bookworm* being slightly faster and a little different to past cycles in not everything was 'ready' just very close & fixable post-release).. FYI: Ubuntu is the same with *fixable post-release* as how Debian was on 12 having set months